# Select a random element from IList<> other than this one

Tags: c#

I have this pattern where I need to select any random element from a list, other than the current one (passed as argument). I came up with this method:

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
{
  Element returnElement = el;
  Random rndElement = new Random();
  if (this.ElementList.Count>2) 
  {
  while (returnElement == el) 
  {
    returnElement = this.ElementList[rndElement.Next(0,this.ElementList.Count)];  
  }

  return returnElement;
  }
 else return null;
}
```

But that while loop has been bothering me for days and nights and I need to get some sleep.  Any other good approaches to this? ie. something that returns in a fixed-number-of-steps ?

Edit : In my case, the list is guaranteed to contain the "el" Element to avoid, and the list contains no duplicates, but it would be interesting to see some more general cases aswell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
{
  Random rndElement = new Random();
  int index;
  if (this.ElementList.Count>1) 
  {
     index = rndElement.Next(0,this.ElementList.Count-1);
     if (this.ElementList[index] == el)
        return this.ElementList[this.ElementList.Count-1];
     else
        return this.ElementList[index];
  }
 else return null;
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the list contains no duplicates. In the genral case - if the list contains duplicates - there is no O(1) solution because the list could just consist of n copies of the element not to return and one has to look at all n values in order to detect this (degenerated) case.

Comment: I think Radu094 wants solution where list contains unique elements, because otherwise his solution may produce infinite loop.

Comment: In my case the list contains unique elements, so I'm gonna accept this answer.

Comment: That will return the wrong value when el is the last element in the list.

Comment: Method rndElement.Next(0,this.ElementList.Count-1) generates values from 0 to this.ElementList.Count-2, so the last element will be returned only if randomly selected element is el.

Answer (score 8):

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
{
  if(this.ElementList.Count < 2) return null;
  Random rndElement = new Random();
  int random = rndElement.Next(0,this.ElementList.Count -1);
  if(random >= this.ElementList.indexOf(el)) random += 1;
  return this.ElementList[random];
}
```

Get a random number between 0 and the list length minus 2.

If that number is greater or equal to the index of your element add one to that number.

Return the element at the index of that number

Edit:
Someone mentioned in a comment which they then deleted that this doesn't work so well if you have duplicates.
In which case the best solution would actually be.

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(int elId)
{
  if(elId >= this.ElementList.Count) throw new ArgumentException(...)
  if(this.ElementList.Count < 2) return null;
  Random rndElement = new Random();
  int random = rndElement.Next(0,this.ElementList.Count -1);
  if(random >= elId) random += 1;
  return this.ElementList[random];
}
```

Edit 2: Another alternative for duplicate elements is you could use an optimised shuffle (random sort) operation on  a cloned version of the list and then foreach through the list. The foreach would iterate up to the number of duplicate elements there were in the list. It all comes down to how optimised is your shuffle algorithm then.

Comment: This will only work if the list contains no duplicates. In the genral case - if the list contains duplicates - there is no O(1) solution because the list could just consist of n copies of the element not to return and one has to look at all n values in order to detect this (degenerated) case. The OP does not state if duplicates are possible.

Comment: Good point, Agg's is a better solution. I hadn't seen his/hers when I added mine. Easy to read too.

Comment: Your solution and Agg's are actually *broken* in some scenarios: Your code fails when `ElementList[random]` and `ElementList[random+1]` both contain `el`; Agg's code fails when `ElementList[random]` and `ElementList[ElementList.Count-1]` both contain `el`.

Answer (score 2):

I have had to resolve a similar problem. Here's what I would do:

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
{   
     // take a copy of your element list, ignoring the currently selected element
     var temp = this.ElementList.Where(e => e != el).ToList();
     // return a randomly selected element
     return temp[new Random().Next(0, temp.Count)];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First count how many matching elements there are to avoid. Then pick a random number based on the remaining items and locate the picked item:

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el) {
   int cnt = this.ElementList.Count(e => e != el);
   if (cnt < 1) return null;
   Random rand = new Random();
   int num = rand.Next(cnt);
   index = 0;
   while (num > 0) {
      if (this.ElementList[index] != el) num--;
      index++;
   }
   return this.ElementList[index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
{
    // first create a new list and populate it with all non-matching elements
    var temp = this.ElementList.Where(i => i != el).ToList();

    // if we have some matching elements then return one of them at random
    if (temp.Count > 0) return temp[new Random().Next(0, temp.Count)];

    // if there are no matching elements then take the appropriate action
    // throw an exception, return null, return default(Element) etc
    throw new Exception("No items found!");
}
```

If you're not using C#3 and/or .NET 3.5 then you'll need to do it slightly differently:

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
{
    // first create a new list and populate it with all non-matching elements
    List<Element> temp = new List<Element>();
    this.ElementList.ForEach(delegate(int i) { if (i != el) temp.Add(i); });

    // if we have some matching elements then return one of them at random
    if (temp.Count > 0) return temp[new Random().Next(0, temp.Count)];

    // if there are no matching elements then take the appropriate action
    // throw an exception, return null, return default(Element) etc
    throw new Exception("No items found!");
}
```

Comment: In my tests, the first version is about 35% slower than the second version, on average. (Probably due to the overhead of using enumerator objects etc in the LINQ calls.)

Comment: Obviously, the performance of Agg's answer easily beats both of my examples, but my aim was to create a "safe" solution that will work correctly even when the list has an arbitrary number of dupes.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
  {
  Random rand = new Random();
  Element returnEle = ElementList[rand.Next(0, this.ElementList.Count];
  return returnEle == el ? GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el) : el;
 }
```

Or in the case you do not like the possibility of a loop:

```
public Element GetAnyoneElseFromTheList(Element el)
 {
  Random rand = new Random();
  List<Element> listwithoutElement = ElementList.Where(e=>e != el).ToList();
  return listwithoutElement[rand.Next(listwithoutElement.Count)];
 }
```

Comment: oops double posted... my mistake

Comment: I like the first solution. You would also need to deal with the case when the ElementList only has 1 item.